# Why does iterating by [i] in a DOM querySelector for loop allow me to use an event listener in any order?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

In the following code I've created a for loop that allows me to produce an alert on any of the 5 buttons located on a simple web page. My question is why does this formatting allow me to click any button to trigger the alert if [i] in my query selector is iterating by 1? Shouldn't I only be allowed to click the buttons in order of their index from 0 to 5? What is happening under the hood that makes [0] in the for loop work for any and every button regardless of order even when I'm technically clicking element[5]?

```
for (var i = 0; 
i<document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++){
document.querySelectorAll(".drum") 
[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
alert("I got clicked!");
});
}
```

Comment: "*Shouldn't I only be allowed to click the buttons in order of their index from 0 to 5?*" - No. I think you need to review how event listener (and maybe asynchronous callbacks in general) work. Let's assume you install only one event listener on only one element, how often do you think will it run when you click multiple times?

Comment: I believe that it would work infinite times, so say the event listener is set for element[0], the first button on my web page, to trigger an alert. I could get the alert to show up unlimited times without refreshing the page.

What confuses me is that element[i] is going from element[0] to element[10] as the for loop runs and iterates i as i++ and this seems to apply to all buttons simultaneously which wouldn't work with a single event listener for one button where the index number matters. What could you please tell me I am confused about?

Comment: Why does it work infinite times, if there is no loop? And when do you expect the code in the line after the one that installs the event listener to run?

Comment: The event listener calls to the function every time I click on element[0]. It listens for a click on that element, hears it, and calls to the function that I pass to it. 

So with the for loop it's listening for a click, I click a button which runs the for loop covering all the (".drum")[i] buttons and calls the function for that particular button as many times as it is clicked?

Comment: No, the loop is not run when the button is clicked. The loop runs when your page is loaded, and installs an event listeners on each element. Then later, when any element is clicked, the respective listener function is called at the time of the click. Only by having multiple listeners installed you can get a choice to click on different elements.

Comment: Ah. Wow, that has contributed greatly to me understanding javascript, the DOM, page loading, for loops, and event listeners. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is equivalent to :

```
// Define an action to do when user clicks, but pass to the next line without waiting that the click event to occur
document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[0].addEventListener(...);
document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[1].addEventListener(...);
document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[2].addEventListener(...);
...
```

At each iteration, we simply define a function to execute when a click is detected. But,
that not means that we are waiting the user really click to pass to the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the equivalency - what confuses me is that if I used one event listener for (".drum")[0] I could only get the alert to pop up for the first button that shows up on my website, thinking left to right and up to down in the html. And (".drum")[2] would activate an alert for the 3rd button to show up on my web page, 3rd one in the html. That said, the for loop allows me to click the 3rd button in my html and it still triggers the alert even though I imagine the code under the hood is (".drum")[0]. This doesn't make sense to me and I'm wondering how it works.

Comment: Oh, i think this it basically triggering the event for ("drum")[0] whenever I click on any (."drum" ) element, correct? So when I click the 3rd button in my html the for loop is triggering the alert for (".drum")[0] even though I'm technically clicking on (".drum")[3]?

Comment: "That said, the for loop allows me to click the 3rd button in my html and it still triggers the alert even though I imagine the code under the hood is (".drum")[0].". Not at all: when you click on a button, regardless of the order, the for loop has already entirely executed. So, each button has been already associated to its the alert action.

Comment: Got it. Wow. Amazing. I'm someone who needs to understand what's happening under the hood to comprehend programming abstraction. You and @Bergi have assisted me tremendously for both spelling it out as well as encouraging me to think it through for myself.

Comment: Happy to have helped. It's a good thing to try to understand what is under the hood, specially in a language such as Javascript :-)

Answer (score 0):

Proof that you have multiple (here, 5), different event handlers (reflecting both the question and a comment you have in another answer):

```js
for (let i = 0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++){
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("I, "+i+", got clicked!");
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="drum">a</button>
<button class="drum">s</button>
<button class="drum">d</button>
<button class="drum">f</button>
<button class="drum">g</button>
```

(It uses `let`, which "localizes" `i` into the `{}` of the loop, practically having 5 different `i` variables - if you try with `var`, that creates a single, top-level `i`, and all of the event handler will display 5, the value of `i` when the loop exits).

If you want to have one event listener acting at a time, you can extend the previous attempt with an `expected` variable:

```js
var expected = 0;
for (let i = 0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++){
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if(i === expected){
      alert("I, "+i+", got clicked!");
      expected = (i+1) % document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="drum">a</button>
<button class="drum">s</button>
<button class="drum">d</button>
<button class="drum">f</button>
<button class="drum">g</button>
```

In this code all event handlers still exist, just they ignore on out-of-order clicks.

And then you can introduce a `sequence` you want the user to follow:

```js
let sequence = [0,2,2,1,3,4,0];
let expected = 0; // just this is an index in sequence now
for (let i = 0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++){
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if(i === sequence[expected]){
      alert("I, "+i+", got clicked!");
      expected = (expected+1) % sequence.length;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="drum">a</button>
<button class="drum">s</button>
<button class="drum">d</button>
<button class="drum">f</button>
<button class="drum">g</button>
<br>||: a,d,d,s,f,g,a :||
```

Of course, `document.querySelectorAll()` is not something what you want to call 2 times for each iteration of a loop, and once more when the loop ends, so you could rather store its result in a variable instead. Also, there is no real need for having multiple event handler functions here:

```js
let sequence = ['a','d','d','s','f','g','a'];
let expected = 0;

function clicky(event){
  let buttontext=event.target.innerText;
  if(buttontext===sequence[expected]){
    alert("I, "+buttontext+", got clicked!");
    expected = (expected+1) % sequence.length;
  }
}

let drums=document.querySelectorAll(".drum");
for (let i = 0; i<drums.length; i++){
  drums[i].addEventListener("click", clicky);
}
```

```html
<button class="drum">a</button>
<button class="drum">s</button>
<button class="drum">d</button>
<button class="drum">f</button>
<button class="drum">g</button>
<br>||: a,d,d,s,f,g,a :||
```

Pity that this answers more what you are presumably doing, than what you are actually asking.